# Dynamic partitioning with dervied column

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to insert data into a Hive table through Dynamic partitioning the table is

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `target_tbl_wth_partition`(
  `booking_id` string,
  `code` string,
  `txn_date` timestamp,
  `logger` string,
  )
  partition by (txn_date date,txn_hour int)

Values

txn_date=20160216
  txn_hour=12

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `stg_target_tbl_wth_partition`(
  `booking_id` string,
  `code` string,
  `txn_date` timestamp,
  `logger` string,
  )

insert overwrite table target_tbl_wth_partition partition(txn_date,hour(txn_date))
select booking_id,code,txn_date,logger from stg_target_tbl_wth_partition;

I am not able to insert with derived columns in Dynamic partition. Any help on how to proceed with such case will be helpful.

Regards,
Rakesh

Comment: I suggest you read a few papers on how Hive stores partitioned data, what is the difference between external and managed Hive tables, how you write INSERT queries for partitioned tables, and the expected format for date literals. But I guess you won't do that, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start from something like that...

```
CREATE TABLE blahblah (...)
PARTITIONED BY (aaa STRING, bbb STRING)
;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true
;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict
;
INSERT INTO TABLE blahblah PARTITION (aaa, bbb)
SELECT ...,
  SUBSTRING(aaabbb,1,5) as aaa,
  SUBSTRING(aaabbb,7,2) as bbb
FROM sthg
;
```

...and make it work; then you can start experimenting some weird and unsupported syntax and see what works and what does not.

Comment: Thank you. I actually did it after reading through docs. and understand that the last columns are the partition values.

Comment: That's Open Source, the documentation is not the priority. And each version has its bugs, regressions... So experimentation is needed > start simple, then elaborate.